# Where can I learn about the "geometry of the equivalence classes of rationals"?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, analytic-geometry, research

I was reading about [the formal construction of the rational numbers as pairs of integers on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Formal_construction) and was interested in the diagram (see below) illustrating the equivalence classes geometrically as the gradients of lines going through the origin. It got me thinking maybe there's some interesting geometry that can be done on this.
For example
computing the sum of 2 rational numbers would be equivalent to "adding 2 of the lines to get a 3rd line", and maybe there's some geometric intuition behind how the 2 lines combine to produce the 3rd line. No doubt this has been studied before, does anyone know where I can learn more about this? I don't know what words I should look up exactly, couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

Comment: The lines just amount to the fact that if you multiply the numerator and denominator by the same number it doesn't change anything

Comment: Try "rational projective line" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Vector_space_construction

Comment: Your question can be connected to the so-called ["Farey sequences"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Comment: You may also be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_integers_(Eudoxus_reals)) construction, which builds $\Bbb R$ as "slopes of approximate lines of points in $\Bbb Z^2$".

Comment: The rational number represented by a line is just the slope of the line, so “adding two lines” just means adding their slopes.

Comment: You might be interested to read more about [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). It's the same concept of “numerator and denominator can both be scaled together without changing the fraction” but extended to higher dimension (more than 2 numbers) and also covering zero “denominator” (slope $\infty$). Most geometry with these is at the level one dimension down, though, which is why it's called projective geometry.